# SQL QUERY data reading

Tags: sql

[image]

I have two table country and Users. I want to view the country name which have user disabled. So i wrote query for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cntr_id,cntr_name FROM
    (SELECT  COUNTRY.cntr_id, COUNTRY.cntr_name, USERS.user_enabled,
           USERS.user_name, USERS.user_id
            FROM  COUNTRY INNER JOIN Users 
            ON COUNTRY.cntr_id = USERS.cntr_id
    )

 AS TAB where user_enabled = 0
```

My questions are :

1. Is this inner query?
2. will the query fetch all the countries (include user enabled) from the database before running outer query?
3. Is there any other method to select?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

- Yes It is inner and outer two queries.
- The inner query will fetch the all rows which satisfy the join condition.
- Yes there is other method to select where you can directly apply the filter in inner query and remove the outer select.

  ```
   SELECT  COUNTRY.cntr_id, COUNTRY.cntr_name, USERS.user_enabled,
     USERS.user_name, USERS.user_id
      FROM  COUNTRY INNER JOIN Users 
      ON COUNTRY.cntr_id = USERS.cntr_id
   WHERE 
       USERS.user_enabled = 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's an inner Query and will fetch what you need, but you don't need your outer `SELECT` query. You could just do it like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY.cntr_id, COUNTRY.cntr_name
FROM  COUNTRY INNER JOIN Users 
ON COUNTRY.cntr_id = USERS.cntr_id
WHERE USERS.user_enabled = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that is inner query.
2. Yes, inner query will fetch all the countries (including user enabled). Outer query will remove those records later.
3. You don't have to use outer query for this.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT C.cntr_id, C.cntr_name
   FROM COUNTRY C INNER JOIN 
        Users U ON C.cntr_id = U.cntr_id
   WHERE U.user_enabled=0
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   SELECT C.cntr_id, C.cntr_name
   FROM COUNTRY C INNER JOIN 
        Users U ON C.cntr_id = U.cntr_id
   WHERE U.user_enabled=0
   GROUP BY C.cntr_id, C.cntr_name
   ```

Comment: @NijilNmk: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied. If you don't know how to accept an answer, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Just curious, why use GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? (I've seen it so many times now, but I can't understand why not SELECT DISTINCT version is used instead.) select union same select is another way to get distinct result :)

Comment: @jarlh: we can use `GROUP BY` even if we don't use any aggregate function so that the duplicate columns will be removed from the result.

Comment: @RagingBull: Yes, I understand duplicate rows are removed, but is there any specific reason to do GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @jarlh: Not much, just an alternative.